# Groovy code works, Then in Jenkins it doesn't. How can I make this work?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to augment the 'load' pipeline step function and I keep getting an error. I have found the code it executes based on the stack trace but I can't for the life of me figure out why it wouldn't just call the code as written.

I have written lots-and-lots of Java code so I know what it's trying to do. I just don't understand why it's trying to do it or how to convince it to stop! The groovy sample works perfectly! BTW: if there is an idiomatic way to do this in groovy/jenkins, I am all in.

Jenkins version: 2.176.1
Groovy plugin: 2.2

test.groovy

```
def someFunction(def params){
    println("someFunction ${params}")
}
def someFunction2(def params){
    println("someFunction2 ${params}")
}
def mainFunc(def stuff){

}
def somemainThingrunFunmain(){

}
def ___cps___21685(){

}
def ___cps___21688(){

}
this
```

main.groovy

```
def loaded = evaluate('test.groovy' as File)

def toAugment = loaded.class.declaredMethods*.name.findAll { !(it =~ '^(main|run)$|^[$]|^(___cps___)') }
def proxy = new Script(this.binding) {
    @Override
    Object run() {
        monad.run()
    }
}
toAugment.each {
    proxy.metaClass."${it}" = { "logging ${it}".tap { println(it)} } >> loaded.&"${it}"
}

proxy.someFunction('hello world1')
proxy.someFunction2('hello world2')
```

outputs:

```
called
someFunction hello world1
called
someFunction2 hello world2
```

Now in Jenkins:

Jenkinsfile:

```
library 'common-libraries@chb0'

node('java') {

    stage('SCM') {
        checkout scm
    }

    def loaded = load('test.groovy')
    stage('experiment') {
         loaded.someFunction('hello world1')
         loaded.someFunction2('hello world2')
    }
}
```

adapted library (in common-library:vars/load.groovy):

```
def call(String path) {

    def loaded = steps.load(path)
    def proxy = new Script(this.getBinding()) { // error here
        @Override
        Object run() {
            loaded.run()
        }
    }
    // remove groovy and jenkins generated functions. Don't touch those
    def toAugment = loaded.class.declaredMethods*.name.findAll { !(it =~ '^(main|run)$|^[$]|^(___cps___)') }
    toAugment.each {
        proxy.metaClass."${it}" = { "logging ${it}".tap { println(it) } } >> loaded.&"${it}"
    }
}
```

exception:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: load$1(load, Script1, groovy.lang.Binding)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1732)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1532)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.constructorCall(DefaultInvoker.java:25)
```

Comment: what about the line where this error appears?

Comment: I explicitly marked where the error is.

Comment: Try to declare your class instead of unnamed.

Comment: @daggett - That will almost certainly not work for similar reasons. You can't have a `static class` in a script - and, if you don't have `static` than you have the outer `this` (in this case, it's the `load` instance you see being passed, or attempted as param 1 of the constructor). I will try it as a named class - what can it hurt